# Skype beta version 5.3.0.1 Not working

Tags: 14.04, skype

My Skype beta version 5.3.0.1 Not working, when I open this in Ubuntu 14.04LTS its showing below message:

Sorry, this version of Skype is not supported anymore.

Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: Update it. The current version is 5.4.0.1.

Comment: @Pilot6 -- 5.5.0.1 is now the current version

Comment: @ravery I have 5.4.0.1 installed and it did not update yet. It works.

Comment: See this http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/getting-version-skype-not-supported-anymore-error-ubuntu

Comment: I checked for updates and now 5.5.0.1 is installed.

Comment: i have found solution,  i have downloaded new skypeforLinex.deb file from skype support portal and installed it using dpkg command.

after installation complete just open skype its working.
version is 5.5.0.1